# Any guides on modern assembly?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to understand assembly and buffer overflows on a 64bit Intel i7 machine. I am having a lot of questions. [I asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462106/what-do-the-cfi-directives-mean-and-some-more-questions) but I don't have any satisfactory answers. I also don't get why there are `MOV` instructions to EEDI, ESI and EDI instead of `PUSH` instructions. Perhaps I should understand assembly on modern architectures first. Can anyone answer my qustions and point me to right learning resources for modern architectures? (I am asking here because people doing REing do have knowledge about assembly and are more targeted audience as compared to the broader audience on SO)

Comment: They answers seemed good to me on SO. I think you just failed to understand them.

Comment: I'm down voting at it's not really a RE question and you got answers on SO and you could have asked for clarification over there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try to understand it. But I asked a lot of questions and I was told only about what's CFI and CFA. :-/

Comment: The general point is to ask a question at a time not seventeen. This way people can answer and know the question is done.

Comment: in x64 the first four arguments are passed via registers so the argument 1,2,3 are moved to the registers  do a function that is function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) and you might see e being pushed into stack or moved into stack

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - I actually want to migrate the question to this site but I don't know how to do that so I simply asked a new question here.

Comment: @PervySage But you got more answers on the SO site, and even though you are trying to understand some ASM instructions so you can RE, this question as it stands does not appear RE realted, just a "what is the CPU doing here" question. Which the SO people already answered. Also your original question/s seem almost completely focused on the CFI and CFA direction tokens, thus the answers are related to your questions.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - I am not sure what you mean by "_answers_ are related to questions". I had asked 4 questions (pardon the numbering. I tried editing them but they didn't seem to change). Out of the 4, 1st is about CFI/CFA directives, 2nd is about the labels and 3rd and 4th are about assembly details on 64 bit architecture. And there is only _one_ answer which talks about _CFI directives_. I understand that it answers my 1st question but not not all of the questions.

Comment: you want to farm rep ask one at a time  :) some one answered you what .cfi (call frame information) and cfa (call frame address ) means in SO .LXXXXX are labels bydefault in x64 GCC labels everything by starting with .L and ending with a numeral so .L1 .L2 ..... .Linfinity are labels  FB stands for FUNCTION BEGIN it seems and FE stands for FUNCTION END and obviously some internal logic of compiler probably depends on them (may be to calculate size rewind address whatever so you should stop worrying about them at this point they so that leaves why .L2 it is there coz there is a branch je .L2

Comment: Hey thanks @blabb. :)
Honestly, I don't care about the rep (sorry, if I appear to be rude; I don't mean to be). I want to know how it works and what's going wrong. If you know, could you also please tell me why there is a size difference? I'd be happy to delete my question if that's answered. Also, if you could answer on SO, it'd be helpful so that if I delete the question here, people who are facing the same problem would get answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Assembly Language for x86 Processors](http://www.asmirvine.com/) by Kip Irvine
- [Optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) by Agner
- [Under the Hood article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx) by Matt Pietrek
- [Skull Security Assembly Summary](https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Assembly_Summary)
- [Assembly Language Step By Step for Linux](http://www.duntemann.com/assembly.html) by Jeff Duntemann
- [Introduction to x64 Assembly](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly)
- [Intel Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech%2064-32_manuals)
- [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/)

Answer (score 3):

I think PC Assembly Language from Paul Carter is a good starting point:
http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/

Kind regards

Comment: I gave a colleague http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tutorials.html and that worked for him. + a lot of easy crackmes.